# Error OpenSSH over TAILS

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, tail, openssh

everyone Im first time poster, wanna know what wrong I'm doing :) help me please. So, Im using tails, decided to connect to remote server (digitalocean) using OpenSSH. Generated public and private Keys, placed to */root/.ssh/*. But when I'm trying to connect *ssh -v root@11.11.11.11* Here is what I get after debug.

```
root@amnesia:/home/amnesia# ssh root@11.11.11.11
FATAL: Failed to determine SOCKS server.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
root@amnesia:/home/amnesia# ssh -v root@11.11.11.11
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/local/lib/connect-socks 11.11.11.11 22
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
FATAL: Failed to determine SOCKS server.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Maybe I just forgot to add some simple step, which bothers me already 3 days..^^ :D

Comment: `ssh -vvv root@11.11.11.11`. What is `TAILS`? What is the `ProxyCommand` in your `ssh_config`?

Comment: srry, maybe Im posting in wrong place. https://tails.boum.org `ProxyCommand none`

Comment: TAILS is an anonymizing GNU/Linux distro based on Debian.

Comment: @DianeTaylor -- Have you configured the TAILS ssh client to use a proxy? It appears that the SOCKS server cannot be found and that ProxyCommand is not set in your local ssh config.

Comment: Also, it looks like you haven't created your own local ssh key. I recommend doing that with ssh-keygen so you don't use the root user over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here;

```
FATAL: Failed to determine SOCKS server.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

It appears as if there is no server listening on the IP address 11.11.11.11.

Is this a domain address known by you to have a ssh server listening on it? If the answer is yes, my recommendation is to not use the root user as someone who can log in via ssh since this is a security risk. I believe it is not allowed per default in OpenSSH.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem using the root terminal, have you tried with the regular terminal from the favorite menu?